# What happens when getline() reads a line that is larger than system memory?

Tags: c++, string, memory, getline

Suppose C++ `getline()` reads from some file that has a single huge line that exceeds the memory capacity of the system (there's no newline before it exceeds memory capacity). What does a `while(getline(cin, line))` loop do then?

And, if I need to handle this possible edge case by throwing an exception or something, how would I do so?

Comment: What happens in general when library functions fail to allocate memory (e.g. `std::vector.resize`)?  Why do you think that `std::getline` would be any different?

Comment: Harder to trap than you might think. With virtual memory fantastic amounts of storage can be allocated, many MANY times more storage than you likely have in your computer. Technically you'd get a `bad_alloc` exception when the program asks for more memory than it can get, but the OS probably won't actually supply that storage until it's used. So it's very possible the system will allow the allocation and then crash and burn later when the promised storage cannot be fulfilled or the system will slow to a crawl as some slower storage is used as swap space to provide more space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `std::getline()` reads up to [`std::string::max_size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/max_size) characters, it simply stops reading and sets the `failbit` flag on the input stream.

`std::string` is likely to throw a memory error like [`std::bad_alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc) long before than happens, though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming the memory capacity of the system is less than the value of [`std::string::max_size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/max_size) (this could correspond to over 8 million terabytes on a 64-bit system <sup>1</sup>), then the `getline()` function would, at some stage, throw a [`std::bad_alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc) exception as the STL implementation tries (and fails) to allocate extra space to the `std::string` object passed as the second argument to the `getline()` call.

So, you would only need to enclose that `getline` call in a `try` block and `catch` that exception.

In the (unlikely?) event that your system *does* have more than the aforementioned `max_size()` available bytes of memory, then the `getline` call would [set the `failbit` flag](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and return when the string reaches that limit.

---

<sup>1</sup> For example, with Visual Studio 19 on my 64-bit Windows system, `max_len()` returns `9223372036854775807`, which is 8,388,607 TB.

Answer (score 0):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) (emphasis is mine):

> Extracts characters from input and *appends them to str* until one of
> the following occurs  ... c) str.max_size() characters have been
> stored, in which case getline sets failbit and returns.

In theory, a standard-complying implementation can have `max_size()` returning a lower value than available virtual memory, in which case the reading will stop there. Typically, this is not the case, and memory will be exhausted first. Appending the next character will trigger the failed allocation handling mechanism, which, by default, is throwing `std::bad_alloc`.

So, to handle the error, you can just `catch(std::bad_alloc&){/*...*/}`.

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu 22.04 it sets `badbit` without throwing `std::bad_alloc`, unless I set it to throw on `badbit`. I suspect it's written in the standard somewhere, but I'm not sure.

The following program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main() {
    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
    std::cout << "ok\n";
    std::cout << std::cin.eof() << std::cin.bad() << std::cin.fail() << "\n";
}
```

when compiled with `g++ a.cpp -o a` and run with `tr '\0' ' ' </dev/zero | ( ulimit -v 500000; ./a )` (gets an infinite stream of spaces, memory is limited to ~500MB) prints the following:

```
ok
011
```

`failbit` here is also set; probably because of a broken pipe or something.

Clang with libc++ exhibits the same behavior.

Moreover, you can clearly see that it's exactly the behavior describe in the standard library's source code: catch the exception, set `badbit`, ignore the exception unless the stream is set to throw on `badbit`. See [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/3dd348d0530c621cc6c851e3cf03a7def69c8baa/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/istream.tcc#L457-L458), [libc++](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/8d2e0c16e691797f11a713a5601dc01e50d8734a/libcxx/include/istream#L1538-L1546).